# Pymill APi get details of all transaction within two timestamps

Tags: paymill

How to get details of all transaction between two timestamps

i tried the following:

```
https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/subscriptions?created_at=1378987463&&created_at=1378987463
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/subscriptions?created_at=timestamp1-timestamp2

Note, your timestamps are the same, in that case you can just go with created_at=timestamp

Comment: https://api.paymill.com/v2.1/subscriptions?created_at=1378987463&&created_at=1378987463